# Flutter android_alarm_manager_plus does not work reliably while try to sent local notification

Tags: flutter

currently, we are facing some problems regarding Background notifications could not
find any solution till now
sometimes it is working but after some time it failed to get a notification.

```
    
    @override
      void initState() {
   
        super.initState();
        AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();
        port1.listen(() async => await incrementCounter());
      }

      Future<void> _incrementCounter() async {
        debugPrint('Increment counter!');
        NotificationService.showNotification(
          title: 'Hello',
          body: 'World',
          payload: 'Payload',
        );
    

 
    static SendPort? uiSendPort;
    static Future<void> callback() async {
        debugPrint('Alarm fired!');
        final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
        debugPrint("Hello World! $now");
        NotificationService.showNotification(
          title: 'Hello',
          body: 'World',
          payload: 'Payload',
        );
     
         // This will be null if we're running in the background.
        uiSendPort ??= IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName(isolateName);
        uiSendPort?.send(null);
      }


      onPressed: () async {
                await AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(
                  const Duration(minutes: 1),
                  // Ensure we have a unique alarm ID.
                  Random().nextInt(pow(2, 31) as int),
                  callback,
                  exact: true,
                  wakeup: true,
                );
              },
```